# [roscore] Following the tutorials ... unexpected output?

Tags: ros, roscore, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

**Following the Tutorial #6.- "*Understanding Topics Basics*"**, at the first step (1.1.1.- roscore), quoting:

*Let's start by making sure that we have roscore running, in a new terminal:*

$ roscore

*If you left roscore running from the last tutorial, you may get the error message:*

```
roscore cannot run as another roscore/master is already running. 
Please kill other roscore/master processes before relaunching
```

**However, if I let one "roscore" process running, and launch a new one in a different terminal Window, I get the following error:**

```
ERROR: Unable to start XML-RPC server, port 11311 is already in use
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method XmlRpcNode.run of <rosgraph.xmlrpc.XmlRpcNode object at 0x8cd3e2c>>
```

And after the stacktrace:

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
ERROR: could not contact master [http://pfc-VirtualBox:11311/]
[master] killing on exit
```

**So, my question is: Is this a kind of "bug" in the tutorial or may I worry about that error being threw instead of the suggested output @ tutorial?**

**Thanks in advance for your answer!**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38775/%5Broscore%5D-following-the-tutorials-...-unexpected-output?/) by [1morelearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/2840/1morelearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2012-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LittleFishLove](https://answers.ros.org/users/33524/littlefishlove/) on 2018-02-02**:
Hi, bro I met the same problem with you , I want to know if the problem has been solved ? If solved, can you give me some help? Thank you very much!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-02-02**:
This problem was solved; see the answer below. If that solution doesn't work for you, you should ask a new question. Asking other users to contact you directly is against the community spirit of the forum, so I've removed your email address from your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Almost certainly a bug in the tutorial. In general, you can't have more than one roscore running; a good rule of thumb is to fire one up, minimize that window, and forget about it.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2